# How to request a certificate in order to deploy business network to Bluemix blockchain?

Tags: ibm-cloud, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I am following the IBM instructions from this [link](https://ibm-blockchain.github.io/platform-deployment/) in order to deploy my business network to my IBM Bluemix blockchain service.

Anyway, I managed to setup connection.json file, but when I try to get certificates from "registrar" issuing this command:

> composer identity request -p bmx-hlfv1 -i admin -s 123

, I get the following error:

> Unknown arguments: p, i, s

I am using composer-cli version 0.10.0, and it seem that "request" part of command is not supported any more.

I see "issue" command, but this is not what I need.

Can anyone help, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

composer identity issue was not in version 0.10.0 of hyperledger composer. Suggest you update your version of composer installed to 0.12.2 which is the latest version as of now.
Information about updating can be found at
https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/managing/updating-composer.html

Comment: This was the case. Thank you.